# Codec preference in sip negotiation (sdp)

Tags: sip, rtp, codec, sdp

Whose codec gets preference in following scenario

Assuming that Caller sends INVITE sdp with preference:

1)Codec A
2)Codec B

Now Callee sends 200 OK sdp with preference:

1)Codec B
2)Codec A

Will the Caller's codec priority gets preference (Codec A gets negotiated ) or Callee's codec gets preference (Codec B gets negotiated).

Also will there a Re-invite be send to lock down the codec?

Answer (score 2):

From my many years of experience what I have seen is the 200 OK from the callee having the chosen SDP in the 200 OK.  So the callee picks.

From the SDP offer answer RFP.. https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3264.txt

> In this model,
>      one participant in the session generates an SDP message that
>      constitutes the offer - the set of media streams and codecs the
>      offerer wishes to use, along with the IP addresses and ports the
>      offerer would like to use to receive the media.  The offer is
>   conveyed to the other participant, called the answerer.  The answerer
>      generates an answer, which is an SDP message that responds to the
>      offer provided by the offerer.  The answer has a matching media
>      stream for each stream in the offer, indicating whether the stream is
>      accepted or not, along with the codecs that will be used and the IP
>      addresses and ports that the answerer wants to use to receive media.

Furthermore...

> Once the offerer has sent the offer, it MUST be prepared to receive
>      media for any recvonly streams described by that offer.  It MUST be
>      prepared to send and receive media for any sendrecv streams in the
>      offer, and send media for any sendonly streams in the offer (of
>      course, it cannot actually send until the peer provides an answer
>      with the needed address and port information).  In the case of RTP,
>      even though it may receive media before the answer arrives, it will
>      not be able to send RTCP receiver reports until the answer arrives.

Answer (score 1):

According to RFC4317 (in the second example), the codec negotiation is not finished yet by now. An second offer should be provided by the caller and lock down the codec, such as SDP in another ACK request. Re-invite is not necessary.

RFC4317:

```
"Alice can support PCMU, PCMA, and iLBC codecs, but not more than one
   at the same time.  Alice offers all three to maximize chances of a
   successful exchange, and Bob accepts two of them.  An audio-only
   session is established in the initial exchange between Alice and Bob,
   using either PCMU or PCMA codecs (payload type in RTP packet tells
   which is being used).  Since Alice only supports one audio codec at a
   time, a second offer is made with just that one codec, to limit the
   codec choice to just one."
```

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4317

But unfortunately not all SIP platforms obey this behavior, at least not the one I'm using right now. It depends on what SIP platform/IPPBX you are using.